# Find the second-order linear nonhomogeneous differential equation, $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are the solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$g_1(t)=1+e^{t^2} , g_2(t)=1+te^{t^2}, g_3(t)=1+(1+t)e^{t^2}$ are solutions for second order linear nonhomogeneous differential equation $y''+p_1(t)y'+p_2(t)y=q(t)$

Find the second-order linear nonhomogeneous differential equation.

Denote $y_1(t)=g_3-g_1=te^{t^2},y_2(t)=g_3-g_2=e^{t^2}$ as solutions for homogeneous differential equation $y''+p_1(t)y'+p_2(t)y=0.$

$$\left | \begin{matrix}
    y & y' & y''\\
    e^{t^2} & 2te^{t^2} & 2e^{t^2}+4t^2e^{t^2} \\
    te^{t^2} & e^{t^2}+2te^{t^2} & 6te^{t^2}+4t^3e^{t^2} \\
   \end{matrix} \right |$$

$$=y(2te^{t^2}(6te^{t^2}+4t^3e^{t^2})-(2e^{t^2}+4t^2e^{t^2})(e^{t^2}+2t^2e^{t^2}))-y'(e^{t^2}(6te^{t^2}+4t^3e^{t^2})-e^{t^2}(2e^{t^2}+4t^2e^{t^2}))+y''(e^{t^2}(e^{t^2}+2te^{t^2})-e^{t^2}(2te^{t^2}))=0$$

Divide the ode by $(2te^{t^2}(6te^{t^2}+4t^3e^{t^2})-(2e^{t^2}+4t^2e^{t^2}) $ and I get the normal form and $p_1(t),p_2(t)$, is it correct ?

In order to find $q(t)$ it's sufficient to substitute one of the nonhomogeneous solutions?

In addition there is an easier way to find the homogeneous ode ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734427/finding-the-general-solution-of-a-non-homogeneous-differential-equation-when-thr?rq=1?

Comment: 1. Find $p_1,p_2$ ,2.Find $c_1,c_2$ such that $y_h=c_1y_1(t)+c_2y_2(t)$ is the solution for the homogeneous ode. , 3.To differentiate $y_h$ , 4.Solve this $\left ( \begin{matrix}
    y_1 & y_2 \\
    y'_1 & y'_2 \\
   \end{matrix} \right )\left ( \begin{matrix}
    c'_1\\
    c'_2\\
   \end{matrix} \right )=\left ( \begin{matrix}
    0\\
    q(t)\\
   \end{matrix} \right )$ and find $q(t)$ , Is it correct ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slightly little more effort one finds that the general inhomogeneous solution is $y(t)=1+(A+Bt)e^{t^2}$. Thus to eliminate the constants move the exponential factor to the other side and derive
$$
e^{-t^2}y(t)=e^{-t^2}+A+Bt\\
e^{-t^2}(y'(t)-2ty(t))=-2te^{-t^2}+B\\
e^{-t^2}(y''(t)-4ty'(t)+(4t^2-2)y(t))=(4t^2-2)e^{-t^2}
$$
to then finally get
$$
y''(t)-4ty'(t)+(4t^2-2)y(t)=4t^2-2
$$

Comment: Thanks , I don't get to find $q(t)$. I get an homogeneous ode  $y''(t)-4ty'(t)+(4t^2-2)y(t)=0$ , how it's possible to find $q(t)$ using variation of parameters method ?

Comment: You just need to insert one of the known solutions into the differential operator. For instance $y(t)=g_1(t)+g_2(t)-g_3(t)=1$. Note that in an affine combination the coefficients just have to sum to 1, they do not need to be positive.